# function returning reversed string in C

Tags: c, reverse

i need to reverse string using some loop function in C
I have this code:

```
char *reverse(char *t)
{
    int length = strlen(t);
    for(int i= (length-1);i>=0;i--)
       t[i]=t[i];
    return t;
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Define "not working". What debugging have you performed?

Answer (score 7):

Your code will never work since

```
  t[i]=t[i];
```

is practically doing nothing.

Comment: since this is more of a homework kind of question, I believe it will be better for you if you completed it yourselves

Comment: It'd be worth mentioning the other error in the code (looping too often so reversing twice) if you're trying to provide hints to enable the OP to fix this.

Comment: @simonc Ya I thought about that too(And I know that was in your deleted answer), but I thought better know what is his intented statements inside the loop, before commenting on loop iteration. As question presented itself now, any kind of loop iteration won't work.. :-)

Comment: Also I must admit, I am not positive on answering the question to the full, since this looks like a question to learn, than implement. Also the OP only asking "*why is this not working?*"

Comment: Ok but remember that once the OP fixes the error you've flagged, his/her code still won't work.  Your answer isn't wrong but it is incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because `t[i] = t[i]` is a tautology. You probably want an extra counter and do something like

```
char temp = t[j];
t[j] = t[i];
t[i] = temp;
```

Where one counter goes from `0` to `length/2` and the other goes from `length-1` to `length/2`.

Comment: Shouldn't you stop the counter at `strlen(t)/2`?  Otherwise you'll reverse the string in the first half of the iterations then reverse it again, restoring the original content, in the second set

Comment: @simonc Right. I'm editing to mention this.

Answer (score 3):

conventional practice is to swap two arrays.. I had practiced it in school :) hope it helps

```
int length = strlen(t);
    /*declare a new array t2*/
    for(int i= 0;i<=length-1;i++)
       t2[i]=t[length -1];
    return t2;
```

Comment: This will be a compiler error.. what is `strlen` in `t[strlen-1]`

Comment: @ Krishnabhadra, pardon, there was a typo.. I have corrected it now..

Comment: Ok.. removed the downvote..

Comment: @kelly, make sure that you have declared an array with `good length`.. access violation comes up when you try to access something that you haven't defined.. here in specific the index of array.. BTW I have corrected a small bug in code.. check now..

Comment: how to allocate t2?  
`char *t2 = malloc( sizeof(what?) );`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
int right = strlen(s);
int middle = end / 2;
--right;

for (int left = 0; left <= middle; ++left, --right)
{
   char t = s[left];
   s[left] = s[right];
   s[right] = t;
}
```

Comment: shortens number of times of looping by half isn't it?

Comment: Yes. But funny enough the complexity is still O(n)!